# Android Studio - gaapt.exe popup causes gradle build error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Each time I try to create a new project in Android Studio, multiple popups come up 
regarding something related to gaapt.exe

[image]

If I go to Windows Task Manager, multiple instance of aapt.exe can be seen running

[image]

Gradle console shows this :

[image]

As a result, the 'Gradle Build Running' never stops and falls into an infinite loop.
[image]

Does anybody else faced this problem? If yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: There something called g.exe virus which add a prefix [g] letter to exe files, i think its involved because aapt which is Android Assets Packging Tool is written gaapt in your cmd window title.